# using setTimeout inside a loop

Tags: javascript

Below is my HTML ocde

```
<div>6</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
```

I want the div's text color to be red in the order of their inner text.First `<div>1</div>` text should display red color and so on

So far I have done this-

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
    if (parseInt(divs[j].innerText, 10) == i + 1) {
      (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          divs[index].style.color = 'red';
        }, j * 1000);
      })(j);
    }
  }
}
```

When I am debugging the values are coming correctly inside the loop and the css for the corresponding div is applied properly but when I am running the code the div's inner text is getting red color in the order I have defined in HTML.

Comment: heard of `setInterval` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Can you describe in English what timing effect you want to happen?

Comment: or even better requestAnimationFrame https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @BenAston — The div with the number 1 in it should be first, the div with the number 2 in it second, and so on.

Comment: @cocco — `requestAnimationFrame` is massively over complicated for something with the framerate we're talking about here.

Comment: setTimeout & setInterval in a loop is safe?... pls this will hang a mobile browser

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47889/alternative-to-setinterval-and-settimeout

Comment: Why don't you just map the nodes into the right order before making them red? Would save you the inner loop.

Comment: ppl should learn js. the web is already full of bad code

Comment: setTimeout & setInterval are evil. Especially if your new to js and want to put it inside a loop

Comment: @cocco — Setting up 10 timeouts which fire at 60 second intervals is not going to hang a mobile browser, nor will a small number of milliseconds of inaccuracy cause a problem.

Comment: but it is the worst approach.

Comment: @cocco — No, it's a good approach. It's simple. It is easy to understand. The drawbacks with it are not remotely significant for the usecase.

Comment: as long as he has only 10 divs there are no drawbacks , right

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s1drgLvg/ css?

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the timeout to `j * 1000` and `j` is the position in the list of divs.

The number in the text is `i + 1` not `j`. You need to use `i + 1` in your timeout value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
divs[index].style.color = 'red';
    }, j * 1000);
```

Should be:

```
divs[index].style.color = 'red';
    }, (i + 1) * 1000);
```

i not j...

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
    if (parseInt(divs[j].innerText, 10) == i + 1) {
      (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          divs[index].style.color = 'red';
        }, (i + 1) * 1000);
      })(j);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>6</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: @TomášZato well it works for me...maybe try a different browser. I don't know what to tell u.

Comment: @TomášZato — It works (it's just an implementation of what I said in my answer). It's very hard to see though (especially for me since I'm red/green colourblind so there's almost no visible difference between red and black characters of that font size on a white background)

Answer (score 1):

Really no need to overcomplicate it.

If you're trying to highlight the numbers in order, you don't need two loops:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      divs[index].style.color = 'red';
    }, divs[index].innerText * 1000);
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<div>6</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
```

One loop, and simply set the timeouts for each div based on its inner number.

Comment: Yup, you made it too complicated originally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it complicated and making a nested loop, just create a recursive call with only one loop. This will make it so that you do not create all your timeouts at once, with varying intervals.

By filtering this list before finding the min, you reduce the search by one item for each item you have to iterate over.

```js
selectInOrder(document.getElementsByTagName('div'));

function selectInOrder(elements) {
  if (elements.length > 0) {
    var item = minItem([].filter.call(elements, function(el) {
      return el.dataset.found === undefined;
    }), function(el) {
      return parseInt(el.innerText, 10);
    });
    if (item) {
      item.dataset.found = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        item.style.color = 'red';
        selectInOrder(elements);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}

function minItem(items, itemFn) {
  var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  var item = null;
  for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var localMin = itemFn.call(items[i], items[i]);
    if (localMin < min) {
      min = localMin;
      item = items[i];
    }
  }
  return item;
}
```

```html
<div>6</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify it with:

```js
var item = 1;
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
clr = setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(divs[i].innerText, 10) == item) divs[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
  item++;
  if (item > i) clearInterval(clr);
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div>6</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Use `setInterval` to run your check every second, which consists of looping over your divs and matching an index (item here). Increment the index after every interval.

Comment: This will work, but the Interval will still be active even if it is not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks this is what i wanted.

Comment: This is horribly inneficient as it loops through all divs every time for no real reason.

Comment: @TomášZato - Actually it's not, and I challenge you to come up with something more efficient than `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('div')).filter(function(e,i,c){
    setTimeout(function(){e.style.color='red'},e.innerHTML*1000)
})`

Comment: @j08691 But that's not what you posted as an answer. Your answer loops over HTMLElement collection 10 times (instead of one) without caching collecton length. One loop is much more clear, faster and involves lower risk of weird behavior (async conflicts of all kinds).

Comment: @TomášZato - For such a simple question there will be no noticeable performance improvement in doing it between the way I posted and the example in my previous comment. Plus, the code in my answer is easier for a novice developer to follow.

Comment: Especially when learning (or teaching) one should stick to the clear and efficient code, so that he can so-so maintain it in real projets. You chose to ignore flaws I mentioned earlier, as well as you suddenly changed from saying that it's faster to claiming that speed does not matter. Therefore I assume this is more about your ego than programming and we should cease the discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I looked on your loop and I can see you're over-complicating things a lot.

## Remarks:

- Instead of double closure, use normal callback function:

  - Wrong:

    ```
    for( var i = ... ) {
       setTimeout((function(num) {return function(num) { ... };})(i), time)    
    }
    ```
  - Correct:

    ```
    for( var i = ... ) {
       setTimeout(myFunction, time, i);
    }
    function myFunction(num) { ... }
    ```
- `innerText` is not standard, so it only work in Google's puppets
- Your inner loop is not exactly clear to me - why not just use one loop

## Working code

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  // innerText is not cross browser and not standard
  var number = parseInt(divs[i].innerHTML,10);
  // Debug
  console.log(number, divs[i].innerHTML);
  // As many seconds as div contents
  setTimeout(highlightDiv, 1000*(number), divs[i]);                      
}
// It's stupid to recreate function() {} foe every timeout
// so I created standalone function instead
function highlightDiv(div) {
    div.className = "timeout";    
}
```

```css
.timeout {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;  
}
```

```html
<div>6</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
  var contentValue = parseInt(divs[j].innerText,10);
    setTimeout(function() { divs[index].style.color = 'red'; }, contentValue * 1000);   
}
```